# How to warn devs after installing or updating npm packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to warn devs in my team to rebuild the docker containers after installing or updating npm packages.

This is because whenever we edit packages in the environment the only way we've found to test them is to clean the entire build and rebuild everything to re-install everything the way it would be installed in the server.

I tried adding comments in the package.json file, but I quickly found out that JSON doesn't support comments.

I tried adding comments in a new section like this, but I was told it isn't ideal.

```json
{
...
"comments": [
    "When installing/updating an npm package, make sure to clean the entire build and install everything again"
]
```

I also thought of adding the comments in the webpack config file, but that seems worse.

What's the industry standard way of doing this?

Comment: *"I was told it isn't ideal"* - by whom? Did you ask _them_ what would be better? What information are you trying to add? As I told you last time you asked this JSON doesn't support comments, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14221579/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/244777/3001761 for options.

Comment: wonder what's the point of reposting [prior deleted question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/426475/31260)

Comment: I just edited the question, does it make more sense now? I thought it would be better to repost with more details.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was told so by a coworker and was tasked with finding a better solution.

Comment: Sorry for any issues I may have caused.

Comment: But is that literally all they said: "it's not ideal"? No objective criteria by which you (or anyone else) could compare alternative solutions to determine if they are indeed "better"? If so, that's useless feedback.

Comment: Maybe you don't need a comment, though: `"postinstall": "echo 'remember to clean your Docker build after installing new packages'"` means people don't even have to look in the package file.

Comment: I think they want it to look like the other comments in the codebase. Something like this https://i.imgur.com/QZqlCWO.png

Comment: Well not to endlessly repeat myself but _you can't put comments in JSON files_. JSON doesn't support comments, just data.

Comment: That postinstall tip looks perfect. I will share it and hopefully they will find it useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you may have an X-Y problem here.

Your actual problem is that it happens (often? sometimes?) that the build environment isn't cleaned after installing or updating packages.

You think that you can solve the problem by reminding colleagues of the necessary cleanup in a comment somewhere in a technical configuration file. I don't think that'll work.

If you want to get the message to your colleagues, a somewhat more effective way would be to scribble graffiti in the restrooms (or put a big poster in the hallway) stating "Please clean up dev environment after installing or updating packages."

If testing in incompletely cleaned environments happens too often, it would probably be better to utilize automation - tests should be run by an automated system in a well-defined environment. It might even be possible to make the integration of merge requests depend on successful run of the automated tests. That way, nobody needs to remember to clean up for tests - the system does it reliably.

If developers run tests in a local dev environment that's not properly cleaned, they may get whatever inconsistent results come out of the tests, but nobody except themselves is going to be affected, because they won't be able to get their code into the master branch unless it tests green in a controlled testing environment.